# How to preserve relationship between rows inserted to table and source SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-insert

I have following code:

```
DECLARE @NewTenant INT = ...;
DECLARE @TemplateTenant INT = ...;
CREATE TABLE FooTable(FooID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), TenantID INT REFERENCES ..., SomeData XML)

INSERT INTO FooTable(TenantID, SomeData)
SELECT @NewTenant, SomeData FROM FooTable
WHERE TenantID = @TemplateTenant
ORDER BY FooID;
```

I need to fill following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #FooTableOldNew(TemplateTenantFooID INT, NewTenantFooID INT);
```

I have figured few ways to do this, but all of them seems to be unnecesary verbose, like:

```
SELECT Old.FooID OldFooID, New.FooID NewFooID
INTO   #FooTableOldNew
FROM (SELECT FooID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FooID) as RowNumber FROM FooTable WHERE TenantID = @TemplateTenant) Old
INNER JOIN (SELECT FooID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FooID) as RowNumber FROM FooTable WHERE TenantID = @NewTenantID) New
ON Old.RowNumber = New.RowNumber
```

At least 4 lines and big risk of mistake when pasting over the same code.

Comment: To be honest: I do not understand your problem... What I understand is, that you want to create new lines based on old lines which you pick as "TemplateTenant". It might be a hint to place a TemplateTenantID column within FooTable (self reference) and avoid your "OldNew-Table". All this information is easier to query than to write in depending tables.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more

Comment: @Shnugo: I don't want to place TemplateTenantID in ~20 tables only to simplify one rarely used stored procedure. Yes, it's possible to add column in SP and remove it after procedure is executed, but isn't it overkill?

Comment: @Moumit: What should I clarify?

Comment: What you should clarify??? Well, the problem :-) Now you suddenly speak about ~20 tables, a Stored Procedure... Just out of my feelings: Something is much to complicated here...

Comment: OK. I have to create a stored procedure that creates new tenant based on template tenant. I need to copy data in ~20 tables. To efficiently do this I want to find the best approach to preserve relationship between old and new IDs. My goal is to easily copy rows in mapping tables.

Comment: @Ginden .. you might be forget .. that you asked the question .. so it is very easy to you to know what is the problem .. not to rest? i did not understand your last query .. does `FooTable` contains both `old` & `new` values?

Answer (score 0):

No need to maintain relation between rows because you are passing both Old and New Tenantid as a parameter , so you can simply use Subquery for the same :

```
CREATE TABLE #FooTableOldNew(TemplateTenantFooID INT, NewTenantFooID INT);
INSERT INTO #FooTableOldNew
select (select FooID FROM FooTable Where TenantID=@TemplateTenant )  as Old,
(select FooID FROM FooTable Where TenantID=@NewTenant )  as New
from FooTable Where TenantID = @TemplateTenant
```

Comment: Irrevalent answer - doesn't work with more than one row.

Comment: based on your posted query there will be returned only Single row  ,because you have putted the where condition for '@TemplateTenant' and '@NewTenant' so it shows that you want only single row Answer and if not then please Explain

Comment: TenantID isn't unique in FooTable and it wasn't implied to be.

Comment: if tanentid is not unique then which @TemplateTenant  you will passed as a parameter , because based in this parameter value you will get  'fooID' and if it is multiple then there can not be multiple Fooid for the same tanent right?